# Brake light switch not pushed in

Tags: brakes, braking, brake-light

I’m an owner of a Opel Corsa C (2000) which had a common problem where water was leaking through the brake servo because the seal went bad. I’ve removed the servo and applied a new seal around it and at the center which connects it to the frame. Now after doing this which is recommended at various video’s/blogs it seems the pedal isn’t reaching the brake switch anymore which causes the brake lights being on all the time. So my question; is it possible to readjust that switch or the pedal itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is usually possible to adjust both...

The pedal adjustment is to set it the same height as the clutch pedal - which needs adjusting depends on where the freeplay is.

The switch is adjusted so the lights are off for the first 3mm or 1/8” of pedal travel so any bumps in the road don’t flash the brake lights.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for taking your time answering! I've investigated the switch itself and I was able to alter it's length by pulling it out a little further using a skrewdriver. The pedal is now pushing the button back in so it's working again! ;-)